# Include slide only in handout (Beamer presentation)

Tags: beamer

My aim is to include a certain slide ONLY in the handouts generated from a Beamer presentation. How to do this?

I know that I can use overlays with `\only` (e.g., `\only<1-1|handout:1`) to specify whether certain elements should be shown in the handout. Furthermore, I can use `\includeonlyframes{frame1, frame3}` to specify which frame should be included.

However, the trick with overlays does not work here since I want to exclude the whole frame from the presentation (i.e., not the handout). The option `\includeonlyframes{frame1, frame3}` is rather messy since I have to define all slides that should be included although I only want one slide to be excluded. Furthermore, I would have to do this manually every time I compile a handout version.

**So is there an easy way to exclude a single frame/slide from the presentation? In other words, how can I define that a frame/slide should only be included in the handout version?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just found the answer. The option `<beamer:0>` shows a frame omitted from the presentation but included in the handout mode. For example:

```
\frame<beamer:0>{
   \frametitle{Title}

     I am a frame that is not shown in the presentation. However,
     you'll find me in the handout.

 }
```